# How does autoregressive training help limit compounding errors at inference?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, autoregressive, lstm

I'm having a little trouble justifying something in my head and was hoping someone could provide some intuition? I understand for LSTM models or models that maintain some state about a sequence that training auto regressively makes sense to help a model learn to manage its context and states. What I am struggling with is if we used a model that did not maintain some hidden state.

For this example lets say that we have some time series x and we apply an AR model to the series. Now say we replace the parameters of the AR model with multiple fully-connected layers.

I believe training the model on one step ahead predictions and applying it to multi step would introduce compounding errors, but I cannot justify this intuitively to myself in my head. Could anyone shed light on this?

I keep coming back to the idea that basically one step ahead training here is just like teacher forcing techniques for LSTMS.

Any insight is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You are correct with your intuition that generally errors compound with time for autoregressive models. This is also true for lstms. This has nothing to do with maintaining a hidden state.
What you're doing in training is teaching the model to interpolate the next value from the past. This interpolation introduces error. In the next state you're predicting on an erroneous value.
Now what are the chances that when you predict from the wrong values you'll predict the correct result? Pretty low generally speaking.

In much simpler models a proof that the norm of the error decreases can be derived, but not for neural networks generally.

You can, for example, look at the result of using an LSTM on tsla stock here:

https://towardsdatascience.com/lstm-time-series-forecasting-predicting-stock-prices-using-an-lstm-model-6223e9644a2f

Where it's super easy to visualize the compounding error effect.